# Can't get mercurial installed on opensuse

Tags: linux, mercurial

I have opensuse 10.2 and need to install mercurial on it. It doesn't have mercurial package so I downloaded mercurial-1.6 but I don't know how to install mercurial on opensuse. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is an `rpm` file, you could try running `rpm -Uvh mercurial-1.6.rpm` from shell as `root`.

Comment: where should I copy this mercurial-1.6

Answer (score 0):

Opensuse 10.2 is pretty old. I'd recommend an upgrade. If you can't, a local install of mercurial should work. See [Local Unix Install of Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/UnixInstall).